# New Question Vs. Old Thread

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

If I find similar questions on StackOverflow that haven't been updated in years (which likely include outdated information), is it better to ask a new question, or continue the conversation in the old thread?

Would commenting in the old thread even get any attention?

Answer (score 6):

We don't really have conversations just questions and answers. If the question is still relevant exactly as written you could provide a new answer, if the question itself is out of date then ask a new one and self answer it (assuming you've searched for duplicates first).

You could comment that the answer is out of date but adding a new valid answer would be much more helpful. We don't really want people to read an answer and then read an "only kidding this one's wrong" comment below it. That's a waste of their time.

Comment: Though if you ask a new question, link to the old one and make the difference completely obvious. Maybe a bounts "outdated" is needed instead?